# Calling PHP webservice from .Net

Tags: c#, php, web-services, wsdl, webmatrix

I have created a Webservice in PHP and I'm trying to call it from my C# code.

When I try to create a proxy using wsdl utility

> wsdl http://localhost:5365/DemoService.php?wsdl

I get this errors

> Error: Cannot find definition for  http://myserver.co.za/sayHello:sayHelloPortType.
>   Service Description with namespace  http://myserver.co.za/sayHello is missing.
>   Parameter name: name

Here's my Webservice code (DemoService.php)

```
<?php

    function sayHello($name){
        $salutation = "Hi $name !";
        return $salutation;
    }

    $server = new SoapServer("greetings.wsdl");
    $server->addFunction("sayHello");
    $server->handle();

?>
```

and my WSDL code (greetings.wsdl)

```
<?xml version ='1.0' encoding ='UTF-8' ?> 

<definitions name='greetings' 
  targetNamespace='http://myserver.co.za/sayHello' 
  xmlns:tns=' http://myserver.co.za/sayHello' 
  xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' 
  xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' 
  xmlns:soapenc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' 
  xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/' 
  xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'> 

  <message name='sayHelloRequest'> 
    <part name='name' type='xsd:string'/> 
  </message> 

  <message name='sayHelloResponse'> 
    <part name='salutation' type='xsd:string'/> 
  </message> 

  <portType name='sayHelloPortType'> 
    <operation name='sayHello'> 
      <input message='tns:sayHelloRequest'/> 
      <output message='tns:sayHelloResponse'/> 
    </operation> 
  </portType> 

  <binding name='sayHelloBinding' type='tns:sayHelloPortType'> 
    <soap:binding style='rpc' 
      transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/> 
    <operation name='sayHello'> 
      <soap:operation soapAction=''/> 
      <input> 
        <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='' 
          encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/> 
      </input> 
      <output> 
        <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='' 
          encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/> 
      </output> 
    </operation> 
  </binding> 

  <documentation>This is Wiley's SOAP server Example</documentation>

  <service name='sayHelloService'> 
    <port name='sayHelloPort' binding='sayHelloBinding'> 
      <soap:address location='http://localhost:5365/DemoService.php'/> 
    </port> 
  </service> 

</definitions>
```

I really don't understand what it is trying to say. Can some one point me in a right direction?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? If you're using .NET 3.0 or above, then you should use WCF, using either "Add Service Reference" or SVCUTIL.EXE.

Comment: Where did the WSDL file come from? you have a blank soapAction in there, usally it is something like <soap:operation soapAction="urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes#sayHello"/>

Comment: @John Saunders I'm using .Net 4.0, but I need to demonstrate in my project that we can use any language for web services, so I have decided for calling php web service in .Net.

Comment: @Re0sless I have downloaded the source code (.php & .wsdl) from Wrox Professional PHP5. Should I add this tag below <soap:address /> ?

Comment: @Re0sless I've added below the <soap:address /> address tag and it still gives me the same error : (

Comment: I meant you should use WCF on the client side. Use "Add Service Reference" to add a reference to your PHP service, or if you want to use the command line, use svcutil.exe instead of WSDL.EXE.

Comment: You don't need the <soap:address /> section to get the WSDL to import, but you will need if to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what is wrong with the WSDL

First the `xmlns:tns` namespace has a space at the start of it

```
 xmlns:tns=' http://myserver.co.za/sayHello' <-- Bad
 xmlns:tns='http://myserver.co.za/sayHello'  <-- Good
```

Next the `<documentation>` node is in the wrong place, it should be inside the `<service>` node like so

```
<service ...>
    <documentation>This is Wiley's SOAP server Example</documentation>
    <port ...>
        ...
    </port>
</service>
```

Your port binding element needs to use the `tns` namespace

```
<port name='sayHelloPort' binding='sayHelloBinding'>  <-- Bad
<port name='sayHelloPort' binding='tns:sayHelloBinding'>  <-- Good
```

Finally I could not get the `soap:body` to import as `encoded`, and had to swap them to `literal`, also note they need a value in the `namespace` element

```
<soap:body use='literal' namespace='urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
```

I believe the `soapAction` element in the `<soap:operation soapAction=''/>` node still needs a value to work correctly, something like `urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes#sayHello`, but it will import without it.

Full WSDL (I caan import this using WSDL.exe without error)

```
<?xml version ='1.0' encoding ='UTF-8' ?> 
<definitions name='greetings' 
  targetNamespace='http://myserver.co.za/sayHello' 
  xmlns:tns='http://myserver.co.za/sayHello' 
  xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' 
  xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' 
  xmlns:soapenc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' 
  xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/' 
  xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'> 

  <message name='sayHelloRequest'> 
    <part name='name1' type='xsd:string'/> 
  </message> 

  <message name='sayHelloResponse'> 
    <part name='salutation' type='xsd:string'/> 
  </message> 

  <portType name='sayHelloPortType'> 
    <operation name='sayHello'> 
      <input message='tns:sayHelloRequest'/> 
      <output message='tns:sayHelloResponse'/> 
    </operation> 
  </portType> 

  <binding name='sayHelloBinding' type='tns:sayHelloPortType'> 
    <soap:binding style='rpc' transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/> 
    <operation name='sayHello'> 
      <soap:operation soapAction=''/> 
      <input>  
        <soap:body use='literal' namespace='urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/> 
      </input> 
      <output> 
        <soap:body use='literal' namespace='urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes'  encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/> 
      </output> 
    </operation> 
  </binding> 
  <service name='sayHelloService'> 
    <documentation>Service Description</documentation>
    <port name='sayHelloPort' binding='tns:sayHelloBinding'> 
      <soap:address location='http://localhost:5365/DemoService.php'/> 
    </port> 
  </service> 
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add the reference to the web service through:

right-click on project file -> add web reference --> type in the url to the webservice and voila!

This should create the necessary entries in Web.config (or App.config) plus the proxy classes that you'll use in your app.